# REST API URL naming by variable

Tags: rest, flask

I want to let people retrieve the resource via different variables. For example, I want to let them search for users via email or ID.

Currently I'm using :

```
https://my-api.com/get-user-by-email?email=xxx@yyy.com
```

and

```
https://my-api.com/get-user-by-id?id=xxx
```

Is this a good practice? If the answer is no, how should I rename this URLs and provide validation so that it only accepts email and ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would not be the good practice to name your resources in such way. Basically, you threat `users` as resource collection which you can filter on by email, and retrieve single resource via unique identifier (`id`), so url pattern would be as following

Search by email

```
https://myco.api/users?email=xx@yy.com
```

Retrieve by ID

```
https://myco.api/users/{id}
```

As for validation, this is implementation, not an interface question and [flask-restful documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reqparse.html) should provide some insights

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if both email and ID is unique? Is it a good practice to use `https://myco.api/users?email=xx@yy.com` and `https://myco.api/users?id=xxx`?

Comment: while both of these entity attribute may be unique on a collection, constrained via rdbms, from REST resource perspective, there should be single id and searchable attribute, so i would recommend doing as original answer suggest. There is also [good discussion on apigee community forum on this](https://community.apigee.com/questions/31164/rest-api-design-query-multiple-identifiers-for-sin.html)